# Daughter's 2005 Nissan Sentra 1.8 SE - No Low Beams - High Beams Fine

Tags: electrical, nissan, headlight, sentra

Daughter was driving home last night from work and noticed "it was very dark" on the way. Turns out low beams won't come on at all. High beams, parking, tail, turn signal and flashers all fine... just low beams won't come on.  Pulled and checked all related fuses, they were fine, good continunity on low beam bulbs as well. I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point -- any ideas? Would prefer to avoid the shop if possible, she drives to work and school every day.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! Would that "switch" be the stalk type switch that also runs the fog lights and turn signal? I just want to be sure and get the right part!  Again, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/low-beam-headlights-dont-work-high-beam-headlights-do?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 6):

It really looks like it's down to the switch, if the high beams work normally (Not just using flash to pass) and both low beams quit at the same time, and you are positive the bulbs are good. The one thing that can fail that would take out both low beams is the switch.

Everything in yellow below is good based on your description of what works. The pink highlight is the rest of the low beam circuit so it has have failed in that area.

[image]

Comment: I had the stalk switch fail in one of my cars in exactly this way.  Everything except low beams worked.  $15 for a new stalk, $15 for a steering wheel puller, & a couple hours of labor.

Comment: Is there a relay that could go bad and prevent the low beams from working?  OP said he checked fuses, but don't headlights go through a relay at some point because of the high current?  Sorry, no experience with Nissans here...  Just curious.

Comment: @JPhi1618 The diagram above shows the entire headlamp circuit, there's not a relay on this car for the headlamps

Comment: Ok, interesting.  Maybe if there was a relay the stalk switch would fail less.

Comment: I once learned the hard way that stalk-type switches tend to fail when you get mad and pull the switch harder that you need to when flashing the lights. Looking at this, you don't need a steering wheel puller to replace the switches. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB_koikw1E0